# Talend date : Parse EST time into UTC

Tags: java, bigdata, talend

I am trying to parse EST time into UTC but getting below Error

```
[statistics] connected    
Exception in component tMap_3 (sample)    
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""    
    at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:898)    
    at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:842)   
    at local_project.sample_0_1.sample.tFileInputDelimited_3Process(sample.java:2271)    
    at local_project.sample_0_1.sample.tFileList_2Process(sample.java:3219)    
    at local_project.sample_0_1.sample.tFileList_1Process(sample.java:2872)    
    at local_project.sample_0_1.sample.runJobInTOS(sample.java:3514)     
    at local_project.sample_0_1.sample.main(sample.java:3365)    
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""    
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)    
    at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:884)    
    ... 6 more
```

I use tMap for convering

```
TalendDate.formatDateInUTC("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm aa",TalendDate.parseDate( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm aa",row9.Start_time))
```

Expected output :

```
Input string : 1/2/2019 8:50 AM EST    
Expected String : 1/2/2019 1:50 PM UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""`

In this line, you can see the value you give to the function `TalendDate.parseDate` which is "", an empty string. This mean that `row9.Start_time` is empty and the function is not able to parse an empty string, this is why you get an exception.

Make sure that value `row9.Start_time` is well filled or add an if clause to avoid parsing the date when it is empty. You could try something like this :

`(row9.Start_time == null || "".equals(row9.Start_time)) ? "" : TalendDate.formatDateInUTC("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm aa",TalendDate.parseDate( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm aa",row9.Start_time))`

Hope it will help.

Comment: Exception in component tMap_3 (sample)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""1/14/2019 12:05 AM "
 at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:898)
 at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:842)

Comment: Still getting this issue

Comment: Any one please help me

Comment: @JyotiKumari It seems that there is an extra " in your string. You should check what is in your data before using the method parseDate.